# What is the best way to auto update a c# app that runs 24/7?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, auto-update

I searched that question over the internet and here , and saw all kinds of different solutions.
The most common solution suggested was ClickOnce . 
My problem is : 
my application is a backup application. 
It runs 24/7 , and I want the update to be automatically without any user interface.
As backup apps usually runs on servers and aren't monitored at all times. 
ClickOnce offers great update solution but it is with user interface and it isn't what I need.
The best thing I could think of is to build a separate app that my main app will call it,
the update app will close the main , download the update , extract the update , and recallthe main app , and then close itself.
I have several problems with my approach :
 1. Where to place the folder(named: Update) containing the update exe file and all dlls that is neccecery to update. Is it a good idea to place it inside my main app folder ?
 2. What will happen if I need to update the update.exe file ?

I would really appreciate if you could shed some light in this matter with your experience.

Comment: Why do you have a winforms app that runs 24/7?

Comment: click once is available without the ui as well

Comment: If you don't want the users to involve in the update process how the new MSI will be downloaded to the local machine ?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically run ClickOnce. Will that work for your purposes?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx